# How to query documents with reference fields parameters in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schemas (`Product`, `ProductCategory`):

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    productCategory: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'ProductCategory'
    }
})
```

```
const productCategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})
```

What I would like to do is to query all the `Product` documents who has a certain `Product.productCategory.name = ?`

I read about population in mongodb but can't really know how to apply it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use aggregation function ['$lookup'](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

```
db.productCategory.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        name: "{category_name}"
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'product',
        localField: '_id', // ProductCategory._id
        foreignField: 'type', // Product.product_category_id
        as: 'products'
    }
}]);
```